# How can I enable anti-aliasing in this PHP GD class

Tags: php, gd

Here I found this awesome class that neatly turns my pictures into circles.

http://pastebin.com/jULhsU8P

But how would I enable anti-aliasing in it? The edges are really sharp as of now:

[image]

I'm not very experienced with the PHP GD library (needless to say). But I tried adding it myself by following this https://www.php.net/imageantialias

Any ideas? Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post the code you've tried.

Comment: That's literally the class in the pastebin. This is the usage:

$sourceimg = imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg');

$crop = new CircleCrop($sourceimg);
$crop->crop()->display();

Comment: In what way did you try using/adding the `imageantialias` function?

Comment: I'd be inclined to try creating the circular mask twice as big as required, and then shrink it down by half - with the intention that the inside edges of the circle would be alpha-blended, and thus when it is applied it appears much smoother.

Comment: @halfer Under "public function crop()". Also, thanks for your second answer. I'll try.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I seem to be getting nowhere. Basically, the code here does exactly what I want, except without anti-aliasing. http://pastebin.com/6udtTUmf

Comment: I'll be gifting a Humble Mobile Bundle 3 (games for android) to the person who can provide a quick solution.

Comment: Well, try the resize strategy - you'll need to amend the class for that.

Comment: Still no luck. Thanks for trying to help me though.

Comment: The problem is that it uses [imagefill](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefill.php) for marking corners and this function is not doing anti-aliasing by nature.
The only way is to rewrite the crop() algorithm making transparency in some other way.